# Image under $T_j$ of the basis vectors $e_1$ and $e_2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

> Define the *linear transformation*. Decide which of the mappings of $\mathbb R^2$ to itself given below are *linear*.
>
> $$\begin{align}T_1(x,y)&=(x+2y,y-2x)&T_2(x,y)&=(x,2x+y)\\T_3(x,y)&=(1-y,x+2)&T_4(x,y)&=(2x-y,-4x+2y)\end{align}$$
>
> Answer the following questions **only** for the mappings that are linear:
>
> (a) Write each map in matrix form.
>
> (b) Determine the image under $T_j$ of the basis vectors $e_1,e_2$. Plot roughly the image set $T(U)$ of the unit square $U=\{te_1+ue_2|0\le t,u\le1\}\subset\mathbb R^2$ in your answer book.

With regard to part B, I understand how to find the image under $T_j$ but I don't understand how to plot the image set $T(U)$ of the unit square $U=\{te_1 + ue_2 | 0 \le t, u\le 1 \}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since linear maps preserve convexity and the unit square is convex, if you find the images of the vertexes of the unit square and plot their convex hull you should have what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, since theres 3 transformations - do I do a new diagram per linear map

Comment: new to stack exchange, how do i go about doing that? It doesnt let me up vote it

Comment: There is a check mark close to the up / down vote arrows. It's ok if you can't find it.